# Django - take users form input and create a link in a certain part of the input?

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, django-forms, user-input

This is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    actualPost = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And this is my forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['actualPost']
    widgets = { 'actualPost' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'maxlength':200}) }
```

This is my views.py:

```
def createPostView(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
            stringPost = form.cleaned_data['actualPost'] #I'm assuming stringPost will now be the string version of the users input
            findLinks(stringPost)
            newPost = Post(actualPost = form.cleaned_data['actualPost'])
```

So basically in the view, after getting the string version of the users input / post, I plan on sending that string to a function called findLinks. This is the findLinks function:

```
def findLinks(postString):
    word = ''
    totalLength = len(postString)
    for i in postString:
        if i=='@': #basically, I want anything after an '@' sign to be a link.. 
                   #so if the post is "Go to @www.google.com to search for anything"
                   #I want www.google.com to be a link 
            indexOfSign = postString.index(i)
            while ((indexOfSign != totalLength-1) and (postString[indexOfSign+1] != '')):
                 word += htmlString[indexOfSign+1]
                 indexOfSign += 1
    return word
```

The function does return the word after the '@' sign. So now that it returns the word after the @ sign, how I do safely make that word a link so that when I put the post in a template, then when I view the template, the word after the @ sign will appear as a link?

One possible way I was thinking was, in the python function, basically return the string version of the post except with the word after the @ sign wrapped around with "" and "", but this will not work because for safety reasons, Django interprets user input as a raw string rather than code, correct?

I don't want to force Django to interpret Post's as code rather than raw string because that will cause security issues. Is there any way for me to safely take the users input and save it to the database and in the template, make all words which come after the '@' sign a link?

Comment: can you not just wrap the content in `<a href="{{url|safe}}">blah</a>` in the template, where `url` is sent in the context?

Comment: @karthikr The user is allowed to make any post he wants.. so say the users post is "this is a sample @-text (I put a dash beside the at sign cuz SO assumed I was directing the message to someone by using the at sign) post". After I save this post in the database and then redisplay the post in the template, I want the word 'text' to be a link to /text/.. so basically it links to whatever the word is.

Comment: Ok, my example would still work - `url` is a misnomer - just use any context variable.

Comment: @karthikr hm, I'm not sure what you mean.. The user fills in the form and clicks submit. In the view, I receive the form and the form is valid so I save it to the database by doing "Post (actualPost=form.cleaned_data ['actualPost']".. assuming that the view which displays the post is "post = Post.object.all ()" and passes post as a variable to the template, then in the template, I would be able to display the post by "for post in post.. post.actualPost)"... at what point can I wrap the word which comes after the at sign in a link tag?

Comment: Check the answer - that is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a class method like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    actualPost = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_link(self):
        if self.actualPost and '@' in self.actualPost:
            return self.actualPost.split('@', 1)[1]
        return None
```

and in the template

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    {% if post.get_link %}
        <a href="/{{ post.get_link }}/">Blah </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hm wait, blah should actually be 'post.actualPost' and the whole post shouldn't be the link, how would I make it so that just the word after the @ sign is a link which links to '/wordAfterTheAtSign/'?

Comment: That is exactly what `{{ post.get_link }}` is doing.. See the helper function in `class Post` You can get rid of your `findLinks` method..

Comment: yea the helper function gets rid of findLinks which is good, but okay so going step by step (correct me if I'm wrong), helper function searches actualPost for an @ sign.. If there is an @ sign, helper function returns the word after the @ sign. The template checks if post.get_link exists. If it does exist (if post.actualPost has an @ sign) then it wrap the word blah with an anchor tag which links to the word which comes after the at sign (the word which helper function returned). Am I understanding the code correctly?

Comment: You are awesome.  You got it right. If you are so concerned, just replace `Blah` with `{{post.actualPost}}`

Comment: alright, okay so I want the template to display the entire post.actualPost and make Only the word after the @ sign be a link (the entire post is not a link, only the word after the @ sign is a link) which links to the word itself. The post remains the same except the word after the @ sign is a link. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you check my previous comment ? That is exactly what this code is doing.

Comment: okay so I just did what you said (I also replaced blah with post.actualPost).. basically what it does is that it makes the entire post.actualPost a link. I need it so that Only one word in the post is a link. Assume the post which the user created is 'this is @a sample post'... After creating the post, your code displays it in the template like this: "<a href='/a/'>This is a sample @post</a>"... what I need is this -> "This is a sample @<a href='/a/'>post</a>".. you see the difference?

Comment: It is really simple. I will let you figure that out. Hint: You can just create another method that gives you the first part. Ill let you try it out, and it it does not work - i can help you